# Spring rest service api call from oauth2 secured rest web service

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I have two web service both are resource server of same authorisation server(oauth2)
Now i want one web service to call endpoint of other which is secured using client credential grant.
Previously i had used Oauth2RestTemplate for the same but now its not available with the latest spring security 5
I tried using resttemplate which will call oauth2/token endpoint with client credentials of other service but it failed.
WHat should be the approach? any help around it would be great

Answer (score 0):

You can simply invoke it through RestTemplate by passing following headers to token endpoint:

> grant_type : client_credentials

> client_id : *your client id*

> client_secret : *your client secret*

> scope : *oauth scope you need*